# How can I compare two NSTimeInterval type object

Tags: objective-c, ios, nstimeinterval

Some thing like this:

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) NSTimeInterval *startTime;

AVAudioPlayer *player;
```

And I want to do this

```
if (self.player.currentTime  > sub.startTime) {
    do something...
}
```

I think they are both `NSTimeInterval` type data, why I can't do this?

If I change the up code like this

```
if (self.player.currentTime  > 5) {
    do something...
}
```

It can works very well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSTimeInterval` is just a typedef of `double`.  It's not an Objective-C object, so you should probably *not* use a pointer as your property.  You should just use a plain `NSTimeInterval`:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval startTime;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. 
And I fixed it like this.

@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *startTime;

if (self.player.currentTime > [sub.startTime doubleValue]) {
    do something...
}
And it's done.

Answer (score 3):

NSTimeInterval is declared like this

```
typedef double NSTimeInterval;
```

You can implement some helper method like this

```
static double NSTimeIntervalEqualCompareThreshold = 0.01;

NSComparisonResult NSTimeIntervalCompare(NSTimeInterval time1, NSTimeInterval time2)
{
    if (abs(time2 - time1) < NSTimeIntervalEqualCompareThreshold) {
        return NSOrderedSame;
    } else if (time1 < time2) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    } else {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }
}
```

Comment: It may a good idea to use `DBL_EPSILON` instead `NSTimeIntervalEqualCompareThreshold`.

Comment: What's the reason for creating something like NSTimeInterval if it only wraps a `double`?